# Hide NavigationView pane completely

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is there a way to hide the NavigationView pane in an UWP app but still showing the Frame control inside of it?

A little background info: I'm trying to implement a UI mode where the user is locked to some specific screens only. The user should be able to navigate in a "guided" way but not be able to navigate freely. Disabling or hiding of the NavigationItems is not enough as it could be confusing. It should be totally clear to the user that, if he wants to navigate freely again, he has to leave this locked state of the app.

I'm using the NavigationView from the [WinUI](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/) library.

Here is a simplified snippet of my NavigationView XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <muxc:NavigationView x:Name="MainNavView"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            ItemInvoked="OnNavigationViewItemInvoked"
                            AlwaysShowHeader="False"
                            PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
                            IsBackButtonVisible="Auto"
                            BackRequested="MainNavView_BackRequested">
        <muxc:NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
            ...
        </muxc:NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            ...
        </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <muxc:NavigationView.PaneFooter>
            ...
        </muxc:NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        <Frame x:Name="RootFrame"
                Navigated="RootFrame_Navigated" />
    </muxc:NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [IsPaneVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.ispanevisible?view=winui-2.3) property you can determine whether the pane is shown. When you want to hide the pane, set IsPaneVisible as false.

```
MainNavView.IsPaneVisible = false;
```

When you want to show the pane, if you are still on the page which declare the navigationView, directly set the IsPaneVisible as true.

```
MainNavView.IsPaneVisible = true;
```

**Or** if you are on another page, you can declare a static MainPage instance, then call the show method.

MainPage.cs:

```
public static MainPage Current;
public void showPane()
{
    MainNavView.IsPaneVisible = true;
}
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Current = this;
}
```

AnotherPage.cs:

```
MainPage.Current.hidePanel();
```

Comment: I totally missed out on the `IsPaneVisible` property... Thank you for your answer.